# Automated Incremental backup sql only 5 days

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is my final hopes for expecting answer. Question is: **How to do automated incremental backup in SQL Server only for 5 days?** and how to schedule in task schedule tool. Please help me.

Comment: What does incremental backup for only 5 days mean? We need some clarification of what you are trying to accomplish before we can help.

Comment: As you mentioned about task scheduler,  are you taking the backup throuh any third party tool?

Comment: I am completely new to sql server....... just I am thinking about how to do incremental backup.....If any tool is there please let me know.....

Answer (score 1):

You might be confusing differential backups with incremental Backups.SQLServer doesn't have a concept of incremental backups..

You might get incremental effect (only backup what has been changed,from last backup) using Tlog*..Idea goes like this..

1.Take a Full Backup
2.Each day, by the end of day take Tlog backup

To Clarify,When you need to restore the backups /make database usable,you will need to restore Fullbackup ,followed by Tlog backups in order

*This is very Risky since ,it reduces your risk of restoring to a point in time

Comment: A transaction log backup can work only if all previous backups since the last full/differential backup are available. Without them, you simply can't perform a restore.

Answer (score 0):

You can [create a maintenance plan in SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189953.aspx) containing 2 parts:

- A back up task for executing a backup every day (or every 5 days)
- A clean up task for deleting all the backups older than 5 days.

Once created, you can plan it as a job in SQL Agent. Here's a great example about how to do it: [Create a maintenance backup plan in SQL Server 2008 R2 using the wizard](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/create-a-maintenance-backup-plan-in-sql-server-2008-r2-using-the-wizard/) by Kyle Laffoon.

Comment: there are saying Right-click the Maintenance Plans folder but in my sql server I do not have under Management folder..... Just I have only three floder Policy Management,Extended events, SQL server logs......

Comment: @VinayakaN, in the MSDN documentation of SQL Server 2012, paragraph [Before You Begin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189953(v=sql.110).aspx#Anchor_0), it said that _To create or manage Maintenance Plans, **you must be a member of the sysadmin** fixed server role._ Are you system administrator?

Comment: @VinayakaN, then I'm sorry that this answer won't be suitable for you :/